# Azure authentication not working in JMeter after apparently correct correlation

Tags: azure, authentication, oauth-2.0, jmeter, correlation

I am trying to develop a JMeter script for performance testing an application with Azure (Oauth2) authentication. Right now I am stuck with the automation of the login process.

These are the relevant requests I have in the script:

1. **Access to login screen: GET [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant_id%7D/oauth2/v2.0/authorize)**
   with the following parameters:

- sso_reload=true
- scope=openid profile offline_access https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read
- response_type=code
- redirect_uri=https://${server}/azure-ad-interface-provider/login/getAuthCode
- state=${state} (captured in previous step)
- nonce=${nonce} (captured in previous step)
- client_id=${client_id} (captured in previous step)
- response_mode=query

From this request I capture the following parameters to be used later on:

- sCtx
- flowToken
- canary
- apicanary
- hpgrequest-id
- client-request-id

2. **Enter username: POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/GetCredentialType?mkt=en-US** with the following JSON body:
   {"username":"${username}","isOtherIdpSupported":true,"checkPhones":false,"isRemoteNGCSupported":true,"isCookieBannerShown":false,"isFidoSupported":true,"originalRequest":"**${sCtx}**","country":"${country}","forceotclogin":false,"isExternalFederationDisallowed":false,"isRemoteConnectSupported":false,"federationFlags":0,"isSignup":false,"flowToken":"**${flowToken}**","isAccessPassSupported":true}*

This request has a correct response, a JSON with the information about the user and the session to be opened.

3. **Enter password: POST [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/login](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant_id%7D/login)** with the following parameters:

- PPSX
- IsFidoSupported=1
- ps=2
- hisScaleUnit=
- hpgrequestid=**${hpgrequestid}**
- i13=0
- login=${username}
- type=11
- LoginOptions=3
- flowToken=**${flowToken}**
- psRNGCEntropy=
- loginfmt=${username}
- isSignupPost=0
- NewUser=1
- canary=${canary}
- hisRegion
- ctx=**${sCtx}**
- psRNGCDefaultType=
- CookieDisclosure=0
- lrtPartition=
- i21=0
- lrt=
- psRNGCSLK=
- passwd=${password}
- FoundMSAs=
- fspost=0

This request is supposed to be returning a response like this:

```
<!-- Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" class="" lang="es">
<head>
    <title>**Sign into the account**</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, user-scalable=yes">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://aadcdn.msftauth.net" crossorigin>
<meta http-equiv="x-dns-prefetch-control" content="on">
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//aadcdn.msftauth.net">
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//aadcdn.msauth.net">

    <meta name="PageID" content="**ConvergedTFA**" />
...
```

and this request should also return the persistant cookies to be used by the script to keep the session opened.

However, it is returning:

```
<!-- Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" class="" lang="es">
<head>
    <title>**Redirecting**</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, user-scalable=yes">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
    <meta name="PageID" content="**BssoInterrupt**" />
...
```

And no cookies are returned. So the script fails in the next step because login is not effectively performed.
I am using Cookie Manager as well. Actually the rest of the cookies are being generated as expected, until this last step.

Could you please advise about what I might be doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're absolutely sure that your last request is correct and you properly correlated each and every dynamic value given the last request is a redirect it might be sufficient to just repeat it using the URL from the [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) header.

Alternatively most probably your last request is malformed, cross-check it with the one which the real browser sends and make sure that it looks exactly the same (apart from dynamic values which needs to be correlated). Better using a 3rd-party sniffer tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) so you would be able to compare the requests side-by-side.

The most suspicious part is `NewUser=1`, given you're logging in with the existing user I would expect it to be `0`.

I also don't think you need to send values for `ctx` and `canary` parameters (however your application migth be configured differently) at the last request.

You can take a look at [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-oauth) with JMeter article in general and at [atlassian-microsoft-oauth.jmx](https://github.com/aboyfromipanema/jmeter-oauth/blob/main/atlassian-microsoft-oauth.jmx) example test plan in particular.

Comment: Hi Dimitri,
Many thanks for your answer. Thanks for the suggestion about Fiddler. Actually it is what I used to know what the correct response should be.
The problem is that even though the response body contains the "Redirecting...", in fact it is not an actual redirection. It is a HTTP 200, not a 302, so no Location header is present in the response.
I have tried with NewUser=0, with the same outcome. 
I have also tried removing ctx and canary parameters and I get an error in the response ("strServiceExceptionMessage":"AADSTS90100: ctx parameter is empty or not valid").

Answer (score 0):

Rodrigo Camino,
You will have to call the Follow-up request after Login, URL for or this to be picked up from first Login request , other parameters to be sent same. [My variables are same as that of you , only I removed i19 field]

[Login Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJxBH.png)

[Login Follow-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1JWS.png)

[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCL08.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue , then I noticed that I had User-Agent field missing from **HTTP Header manager** in Jmeter for https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant_id%7D/login

Just add User-Agent and it will work.

**User-Agent**  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:108.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/108.0